# How to pass an Expression into a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I can pass an Expression into the LINQ Select() method:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetInfo(long limit, Expression<Func<MyType, T>> selector)
{
    return DbSet.Where(t => t.id < limit).Select(selector)
}
```

How can I do the same using LINQ-style query?

```
public IQueryable<T> GetInfo(long limit, Expression<Func<MyType, T>> selector)
{
    var result = from t in DbSet
                 where t.id < limit
                 select selector(t) // doesn't work
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can use:

```
var result = (from t in DbSet
             where t.id < limit
             select t).Select(selector);
```

... but you can't just use the selector *inside* the query expression, as that's implicitly wrapping an extra layer that you don't want.

It's not clear why you want to use query expressions here anyway, mind you - I would strongly recommend that you become comfortable with both styles of LINQ and use whatever's more appropriate at the time - which in this case is the style you have in your original code.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, unfortunately. The point is to pass expression to the query.

Comment: @enkryptor: It does answer the question: you *can't* use it within the query expression... and you don't need to, basically. If you could be clearer about why you're trying to do that, we can provide alternatives...

Comment: I got it...Could you please edit your answer - add "You can't" as a title before explanations?

Comment: @enkryptor: I'm happier with it as it is, to be honest. It shows how to use it *with* a query expression, and then is pretty clear that you can't use it *in* a query expression. I'll italicize "inside" though. (It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve though...)